# Improve the speed of a dilating circle animation in R

Tags: r, animation

I am trying to create an enlarging circle to test the Apparent Looming Threshold of fish. I want to be able to control the radius of the circle and the rate at which the radius increases. 
I have the following code:

```
library(plotrix)
px=1:50
py=1:50
plot(px,py,type="n",xlab="",ylab="",axes = FALSE)#create blank plot
x=25#set x location of circle
y=25#set y location of circle
radius=seq(1,20,by=.5)#set sequence of radii to plot
#plot circle on top of each other to give appearance of growing circle
#at a rate of Sys.sleep(x)
for (i in radius){
  draw.circle(x,y,radius = i,col="black")
  Sys.sleep(1)#plot one circle per second
}
```

The code allows me to change the radius of the circle and the rate, however, if the Sys.sleep(x) is set below 1, the for loop takes too long to process and skips circles in the sequence. Is there alternative to a for loop that would speed up the plotting so that I could get the entire animation to run faster than 1 frame per second? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect rather `plotrix` than the for loop which slows down. You could just plot a normal point and let him grow literately with `cex`; wrap all into a function.

```
growCycle <- function(x) {
  plot(25, 25, xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE, asp=1, col=1, pch=20, cex=x)
  Sys.sleep(.2)  # at least 5 fps
}
```

*Note:* Consider a glance into `?plot` and `?par` for more graphical parameters.

Then use `sapply()`:

```
radius = seq(1, 20, by=.5)
sapply(radius, growCycle)
```

Results in an increased speed of 400 %!

Hope this helps.

[image: circle]